# Show $r=a/b,a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ given $\text{ord}_{p_i}a\geq\text{ord}_{p_i}b$ is a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_t\in\mathbb{Z}$ be primes and consider the set of all rational numbers $r=a/b, a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $\text{ord}_{p_i}a\geq\text{ord}_{p_i}b$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,t$. Show that this set is a ring and that up to taking associates $p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_t$ are the only primes.

I don't think I am thinking of $\text{ord}_{p_i}a\geq\text{ord}_{p_i}b$ correctly. I want to show this is a ring by using the subring test.

$3/2$ and $4/3$ are elements of $r\subset\mathbb{Q}$, but $3/2-4/3=1/6$, where clearly $1<6$.

I know to show primes up to associates, I need an element $c/d$ so that $a/b=c/d\cdot u$, where $u$ is a unit. I think the only case here is $u=1$, implying $a/b=a/b\cdot1$. Are there other units I need to consider?

Comment: I don't understand your counterexample, the primes you're considering cannot include $2$ because $\frac{3}{2}$ won't be an element, and similarly doesn't include $3$ because $\frac{4}{3}$ won't be an element. If the set of primes were any other, then $\frac{1}{6}$ obviously satisfies them and your counterexample isn't actually a counterexample.

Comment: If you're confused about the question, $\text{ord}_{p_i}(a) \geq \text{ord}_{p_i}(b)$ implies that $\frac{a}{b} = \prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{e_i} \frac{c}{d}$ where $c$ and $d$ are coprime to $p_i$ and $e_i \geq 0$. I hope it is clearer now that this would result in a ring.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think it's becoming a bit clearer. Here is an example of what I think should be in this ring: $24=2^3\cdot3^1,40=2^3\cdot5^1$. In both cases, $\text{ord}_{p_i}a\geq\text{ord}_{p_i}b$, so $3/1$ is an element of $(r,+,\cdot)$. Could you elaborate a bit more on the product notation? I'm not sure how the equality with $a/b$ follows.

Comment: I think there's still confusion regarding the question. The primes $p_i$ are fixed and you define the set using them. So for example, choose primes $2$ and $3$, then the set under consideration would be all the rational numbers $\frac ab$ such that the $a$ always has more or the same factors of $2$ or $3$ than in $b$. So the set can contain $\frac 67, \frac{4}{10}, \frac{5}{7}$ but not $\frac 13$ or $\frac 94$. Now if you had to describe all the elements in the set, you would describe it as $\prod 2^a 3^b \frac cd$ where $a,b \geq 0$ and $c,d$ are coprime to both $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your example with $24$ and $40$. Where did you get $\frac 31$ from? (Again, to clarify, you cannot describe the set without specifying the primes first. The primes describe the set under consideration).

Comment: ord(2) of 24 is 3, ord(3) of 24 is 1. I guess I don't understand your initial explanation. Would you mind simplifying your explanation further or submitting an answer?

Comment: The ratio $\frac ab$ is not the ratio of the orders of a number. I'll explain the question since you're having trouble with it. Forget everything about the question. First, choose a prime $p_1$. Now consider a rational number $\frac ab$. Our set $S$ contains $\frac ab$ only if $\text{ord}_{p_1}(a) \geq \text{ord}_{p_1}(b)$. Notice that we are comparing the p-adic orders of two different integers for a single prime, not p-adic orders of different primes of one integer like you did. (contd).

Comment: This condition is equivalent to saying that when we reduce $\frac ab$ to its reduced form, all the factors of $p_1$ will be in the numerator i.e. $\frac ab = p_1^a \frac cd$ where $a \geq 0$ and $c$ and $d$ are coprime to $p_1$. In your question, it's the same situation but initially with finitely many primes instead of one. We are choosing $\frac ab$ such that $\text{ord}_{p_i}(a) \geq \text{ord}_{p_i}(b)$ for all primes in our list. Equivalently, $\frac ab = \prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{e_i} \frac cd$ where $e_i \geq 0$ and $c,d$ coprime to every $p_i$.

Comment: For sake of argument, let $p_1=2$. This is saying $8/5=2^2\cdot2/5,$ right? I think I get the $\text{ord}_{p_1}a$ stuff, but why is it important for $b$? In the example I tried to make, would $\text{ord}_{p_1}b=\text{ord}_{p_1}5=0$?

Comment: Well, $\frac 85$ would be $2^3 \cdot \frac 15$ and yeah, $\text{ord}_2(5)=0$. For  $\frac ab$, without knowing $\text{ord}(b)$, how would you confirm it satisfies the condition? In fact, if $\frac ab$ is in reduced form, all you have to do is check if $\text{ord}_{p_i}(b)=0$ to confirm it is an element of the set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126968/discussion-between-dullandwitlessboi-and-arbashn).

Comment: Also, to answer your last question, $\text{ord}_{p_i}(b)=0$ iff $p_i\nmid b$.

Comment: I know. My question wasn't how to check if $\text{ord}(b)=0$. My question was because you asked why is it important to know ord(b), the condition in the question is $ord(a) \geq ord(b)$, there's no way to check this if you don't know $ord(b)$. My last comment was that if $\frac ab$ were in reduced form, then $ord(b)$ is the only one that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{\operatorname{ord}}$Let $R$ be the given set.

As mentioned in the comments, given rational $r$, $r \in R$ if and only if
$$r = \frac{c}{d} \prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{e_i}$$
for integer $c,d,e_i$, where $e_i \geq 0$ for each $i$ and $d$ is coprime to the $p_i$. Observe that it is equivalent to assert that $e_i\geq 0$ and *both* $c$ and $d$ are coprime to the $p_i$ (we can pull out any extra $p_i$ that are in $c$).
Why is this?
For the forward direction, suppose you have some $r = a/b \in R$. Then $\ord_{p_i}(a) \geq \ord_{p_i}(b)$ for each $i$. So,
$$\frac{a}{b} = \left( \frac{a/\prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{\ord_{p_i}(a)}}{b/\prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{\ord_{p_i}(b)}} \right) \prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{\ord_{p_i}(a) - \ord_{p_i}(b)}.$$

The denominator $d := b/\prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{\ord_{p_i}(b)}$ of the fraction is coprime to each $p_i$, and $e_i := \ord_{p_i}(a) - \ord_{p_i}(b) \geq 0$ for each $i$.

Can you check the reverse direction on your own?

---

Now, let us check closure under multiplication.
Let $r_1 = a_1/b_1\prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{d_i}$ and $r_2 = a_2/b_2 \prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{e_i}$ be elements of $R$, where $d_i, e_i \geq 0$ and $b_1$, $b_2$ are coprime to the $p_i$. Then,

$$r_1r_2 = \frac{a_1a_2}{b_1b_2} \prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{d_i + e_i}.$$

Clearly, $b_1b_2$ is coprime to the $p_i$ because each of $b_1$ and $b_2$ are, and $p_i$ is a prime. It follows that $r_1r_2 \in R$ since $d_i+e_i \geq 0$ for each $i$.

---

Next, we shall check closure under subtraction.
As before, let $r_1,r_2\in R$ with the same notation. For starters, what happens when $t=1$? Suppose $d_1 \geq d_2$.
$$\begin{align*}
r_1 - r_2 &= \frac{a_1}{b_1} p_1^{d_1} - \frac{a_2}{b_2} p_2^{d_2} \\
&= p_1^{d_2} \left( \frac{a_1}{b_1} p_1^{d_1 - d_2} - \frac{a_2}{b_2} \right) \\
&= p_1^{d_2} \left(\frac{a_1b_2p_1^{d_1 - d_2} - a_2b_1}{b_1b_2}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
$b_1b_2$ is coprime to $p_1$ since $b_1$ and $b_2$ separately are, and $d_2 \geq 0$ so $r_1 - r_2 \in R$.
In the general case (for any $t$),
$$
\begin{align*}
r_1 - r_2 &= \frac{a_1}{b_1} \left( \prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{d_i} \right) - \frac{a_2}{b_2} \left( \prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{e_i} \right) \\
&= \left( \frac{a_1}{b_1} \prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{d_i - \min\{d_i,e_i\}} - \frac{a_2}{b_2} \prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{e_i - \min\{d_i,e_i\}} \right) \prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{\min\{d_i,e_i\}}
\end{align*}
$$
The term within the parentheses simplifies to some rational with denominator $b_1b_2$, which is coprime to the $p_i$. We also have $\min\{d_i,e_i\} \geq 0$ for any $i$, so it follows that $r_1 - r_2 \in R$.

The multiplicative identity $1$ is in $R$, so $R$ is a ring by the subring test.

---

> Are there other units I need to consider?

Any element of the form $c/d$, where both $c$ and $d$ are coprime to the $p_i$, is a unit.

Let

$$r = \frac{c}{d}\prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{e_i}$$
where both $c$ and $d$ are coprime to $p_i$ and $e_i \geq 0$ for each $i$. Further suppose that $e_i \neq 0$ for some $i$, that is, $r$ is not a unit.

We wish to show that $r$ is a prime if and only if $\sum_{i} e_i = 1$ (that is, $e_j = 1$ for some $j$ and $e_i = 0$ for $i\ne j$).

- The forward direction can be shown via the contrapositive. Indeed, if $\sum_i e_i \geq 2$, then we can write $r = r_1 r_2$ such that neither $r_1$ nor $r_2$ is a unit (try splitting the prime powers between the $r_j$), and $r \nmid r_1, r_2$.
- For the other direction, it is straightforward to show that if $e_j = 1$ for some $j$ and $e_i = 0$ for $i\neq j$, and $r \mid r_1r_2$, then there must be a power of $p_j$ in either $r_1$ or $r_2$, so $r \mid r_1$ or $r\mid r_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be the given set.
First, note that $r \in \Bbb Q$ is an element of $R$ iff $r$ can be written as $a/b$ such that $p_i \nmid b$ for all $i$. In other words, we have

$$R = \left\{\frac{a}{b} : a, b \in \Bbb Z,\, p_i \nmid b \text{ for all } i \in \{1, \ldots, t\}\right\}.$$

Using just the above characterisation, it is quite direct to note that $R$ is a ring.

Also, it is easy to note that any denominator $b$ is a unit in $R$. Said more precisely, given any $r \in R$, it has an associate $r' \in \Bbb Z$. From this, the question about primes just reduces to finding integers which are primes in $R$. Clearly, any integer which was not a prime in $\Bbb Z$ is still not a prime in $R$. Moreover, any integer prime outside $\{\pm p_1, \ldots, \pm p_t\}$ has now become a unit.

Thus, we just need to verify each $p_i$ is indeed a prime in $R$. The only thing to really check is that $p_i$ is not a unit. This is simple to do.
To now see that it is a prime, it suffices to again work with just integers since every element of $R$ has an integer associate. But now the result follows since $p_i$ was a prime in $\Bbb Z$, to begin with.

---

Here's a more general perspective, if you know [localisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)).

Let $\mathfrak p_i := \langle p_i \rangle$ be the prime ideal in $\Bbb Z$ generated by $p_i$. Consider the multiplicative set $S := \Bbb Z \setminus (\mathfrak{p}_1 \cup \cdots \cup \mathfrak{p}_t)$.

Then, $R$ is precisely the localisation of $\Bbb Z$ at $S$. In particular, it is a ring. (Note that $\Bbb Z$ is an integral domain and so, every localisation can be seen as a subring of $\Bbb Q$.)
[In fact, the checks you would do to show that $R$ is a ring in the first method is essentially mimicking (a part of) the construction of $S^{-1}R$.]

Moreover, since $\Bbb Z$ was a PID, so is $R$. Thus, the question of finding the prime elements comes down to finding all the prime ideals of $R$. Again, the general theory of localisation tells us that prime ideals of $R$ are precisely those of the form $S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal not intersecting $S$. In our case, this is equivalent to $\mathfrak{p} \subset \bigcup_i \mathfrak{p}_i$. By [prime avoidance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma), this is possible iff $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{p}_i$ for some $i$ or $\mathfrak{p} = 0$.

This answers the question about all primes in $R$ as well.